# jquery addClass adding a class to div but also removing it instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to remove a class from `div` (hide class) and want to add a class (show class).
i am using `addClass` and `removeClass` for this but this behaving very funny.

```
$('#table-csv').removeClass('hideDiv')
```

it is removing class from `div` but adding it again instantly.
I am doing it in `ajax` success response from Django view.

I tried lots of solution available on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and other websites but no luck.

`css` classes:

```
.hideDiv{
    display: none;
}
.showDiv{
    display: block;
}
```

my script:

```
  $.ajax(
{
    type:"POST",
    url: "/graph/upload-csv/",
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    data:{
      input: input,
      output: output,
    },
    success: function( data ) 
    {

      $('#table-csv').addClass('showDiv').removeClass('hideDiv');
    }
})
```

**when I am trying to `removeClass` on simple button click then it is working fine. problem is only when I am doing it in ajax success response**

I know I will get lots of down votes for this question but I need help.

Comment: "it is removing class from div but adding again it instantly" <-- how do you know?

Comment: i am seeing it in inspect element and also div show and disappear.

Comment: Can you show what does showDiv and hideDiv do?@vikrant

Comment: @ShubhDixit please see updated code

Comment: What browser and version are you using?  Does this happen in other browsers?  If you try not chaining but using separate statements for adding and removing a class, what happens?  Have you tried something like .toggleClass('showDiv hidDiv')?

Comment: That should work as expected. Do you have any other code manipulating these elements on other events? What other code do you use to hide the div.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need two separate class one to hide another to show . Instead create a single class

```
.hide{
 display:none;
}
```

When required to hide the element do `$(elementSelector).addClass('hide')` and when required to show do `$(elementSelector).removeClass('hide')`

Comment: search the entire code base , if there is a duplicate of the `id` and for same function which is adding the class. You can also verify by renaming the existing css `hide` class, so you will able to understand if anywhere else in the code there exist a function which is adding the class

Comment: i checked id is unique and i also try by renaming classes and id, but it is not working

Comment: put a `console.log` inside `success` and see how many times it is logging

Comment: i put console log inside success  and getting {'name':4}

Answer (score 0):

Insert in the DOM the code from the AJAX call and after remove the class in the `success` function :

```
$.ajax({
 ...
 success : function (data) {
     $("#div").html(data).find('#table-csv').addClass('showDiv').removeClass('hideDiv');
 },
});
```

My suggestion: make some `console.log` for the 'data' in the success function to test the response.

Comment: what is first '#div'

Comment: i paste it exactly but not working...nothing happen neither deleting any nor adding any class

Comment: '#div' is a sample. Make some console log of data

Comment: in data as of now i am getting {'name':4}

Comment: this is just a sample data i will get a django querset in data

Answer (score 0):

Do you declare the hide class inline like this:

```js
$('#table-csv').addClass('showDiv').removeClass('hideDiv');
```

```css
.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}

.showDiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideDiv">
test
</div>
```

That doesn't seem to work. Try to remove it then and add the class trough javascript.

```js
$('#table-csv').addClass('hideDiv');
$('#table-csv').addClass('showDiv').removeClass('hideDiv');
```

```css
.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}

.showDiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
test
</div>
```

Comment: I declared it inline, now i tried your approach. i am adding hide class on page load using jquery and trying to remove hide class in ajax success  response but behaving like before.

Comment: @vikrant are you sure you get a successful response from your ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are using `ajax` you can not access UI thread, it seems they have different thread, for this reason an easy way is saving `dom` element to a variable and then manipulate it in `ajax` success like, in the other words `success` event won't access `dom` elements or another UI objects truly :

```
var myElement =  $('#table-csv');
$.ajax(
{
    type:"POST",
    url: "/graph/upload-csv/",
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    data:{
      input: input,
      output: output,
    },
    success: function( data ) 
    { 
       myElement.addClass('showDiv').removeClass('hideDiv');
    }
})
```

or this may  because of calling `removeClass` and `addClass` successively, this is better to call them separately like :

```
$.ajax(
{
    type:"POST",
    url: "/graph/upload-csv/",
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    data:{
      input: input,
      output: output,
    },
    success: function( data ) 
    { 
        $('#table-csv').addClass('showDiv');
    },
   stop: function( data ) 
    { 
        $('#table-csv').removeClass('hideDiv');
    }
})
```